Short fiction story about an habitable planet
Okay so i read this not so long ago, it was a small short story about how some scientists discovered a planet very similar to earth on the edge of space. To their surprise, the planet had a small house on it but they never saw if anyone lived there. They called the planet something like "Finisterra" or "finistere". In the end, due to their tools (space ships) not being able to get there in a short time they decided not to travel. The planet was then slowly forgotten by everyone.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be a bit more specific about when you read this?  Past year, past five years...  Did you read this in a physical book or online?

There's a story entitled Finisterra by David Moles, but it doesn't sound anything like your description: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finisterra_(novelette)

I know about the novel. It's not the novel.I read about it in the last 2-3 weeks. I don't think the story is that old either, maybe made in the last 10-15 years. But it was very very short, like a column in a magazine or something like that.
